# Lie derivative of a coordinate form into its coordinate direction

Tags: differential-geometry, differential, lie-derivative

I have to calculate the Lie derivative of $\alpha = d x_1$ with respect to the vector field $X = \partial_1$, but I cannot use Cartan's magic formula (which would immediatly show that $L_X\alpha= 0$).

So the flow is given by $\phi_X^t(x) = (x_1+t,x_2,...,x_n)$, and thus $D\phi_X^t(x) = id_n$, right? Then it follows that $$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}(\phi_X^t(x))^*\alpha = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \alpha\circ id_n = 0,$$
which should be the right answer... but I am not really sure if my linerarization of the flow is actually correct.

Comment: You don’t need to compute flows. You just need to know some basic properties, for example, Lie derivatives commute with exterior derivatives (a fact much easier to prove than Cartan’s formula). Then, you need to know how Lie derivatives act on functions. But sure, this particular case is easy enough to be done by explicitly calculating the flow and pulling back.